# Datepicker in Django and update tables with jquery or without

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-tables2

Good good evening!

I've been thinking for a few days now and using different options to solve the problem - updating the table when a date interval is selected.

I have a table and a form to display data and a calendar.

I'm taking two different values from a calendar and trying to update the data in a table.
But nothing happens to me.

I would be very grateful if you manage to at least suggest something to find an error.
Save me please.

Maybe you will offer a more simplified version without using jquery - I will be very grateful.

models

```
from django.db import models


class EmployeeModel(models.Model):
    empid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    empname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    salary = models.IntegerField()
    joindate = models.DateField()
    class Meta:
        db_table = "employee"
```

forms

```
from datetime import date
from django import forms
from .models import *

today = date.today()


class StockHistorySearchForm(forms.ModelForm):
    start_date = forms.DateField(required=False)
    end_date = forms.DateField(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = EmployeeModel
        fields = ['start_date', 'end_date']
```

views

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django_filters.views import FilterView
from django_tables2 import SingleTableMixin

# Create your views here.

from django.http import HttpResponse
from . import models
from .models import EmployeeModel

from .forms import StockHistorySearchForm


def showresults(request):
    header = "HYSTORY DATA"
    queryset = EmployeeModel.objects.all()
    form = StockHistorySearchForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        "header":header,
        "queryset":queryset,
        "form":form,
    }
    if request.method == "POST":
        queryset = EmployeeModel.objects.filter(
            joindate__range=[
                form['start_date'].value(),
                form['end_date'].value()
            ]
        )
    return render(request, "demo/index.html", context)
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link href="static/js/jquery-ui-1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="static/js/jquery-ui-1.13.2/jquery-ui.structure.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="static/js/jquery-ui-1.13.2/jquery-ui.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="static/js/jquery-3.6.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="static/js/jquery-ui-1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="static/js/myjs.js"></script>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">{{header}}</div>
        <form method="POST" action="">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{form|crispy}}
            <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
        </form>
        <hr/>
        <div class="display_table">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Employee Id</th>
                        <th>Employee Name</th>
                        <th>Salary</th>
                        <th>Join Date</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                {% for instance in queryset %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ instance.empid }}</td>
                    <td>{{ instance.empname }}</td>
                    <td>{{ instance.salary }}</td>
                    <td>{{ instance.joindate }}</td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-mQ93GR66B00ZXjt0YO5KlohRA5SY2XofN4zfuZxLkoj1gXtW8ANNCe9d5Y3eG5eD" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

myjs.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".datetimeinput").datepicker({changeYear: true,changeMonth: true, dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});


});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w50I8.png)

Comment: any hint or information will save me please help
really need help

Comment: In the `showresults()` method, move the setting of the `context` to after the `If POST...` section. You are currently updating the `queryset` variable, but you are not updating the `context["queryset"]` due to the ordering.